# TomCat Page Instead of Jenkins

Tags: tomcat, jenkins

I've just installed Jenkins on my Ubuntu 15.04. The installation was using 'apt-get' command which ended successfully. But now when I browse 'http://localhost:8080' or 'http://localhost:8080/jenkins' nothing worked. Just tomcat server's page is displayed. How can I browse the Jenkins????? Following is the log file errro:

```
hudson.util.BootFailure publish
SEVERE: Failed to initialize Jenkins
hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad: java.lang.InterruptedException
at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:237)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:267)
at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:44)
at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:924)
at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:816)
at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:85)
at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:81)
at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:225)
```

Comment: Is there any error message in `/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log`?

Comment: Hi David, errors are give above from the log file. I've also installed Jave 8 along with Java 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that another instance of Tomcat is already running on port 8080. Try changing the http port in `/etc/default/jenkins`, e.g. replace this line:

```
HTTP_PORT=8080
```

by this one:

```
HTTP_PORT=8081
```

then restart Jenkins:

```
sudo service jenkins restart
```